# Firebase database structure with UID and database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Github repo https://github.com/JesseSoldat/Around-The-World-NG2-Firebase
Firebase JSON data exported to a file is in the repo **FIREBASE_DATA.json**

I have been trying to figure out the firebase database rule. I have read many articles and they all say that I need to do something like this

[image: This is an image of my current database and rules CLICK HERE]

```js
{
  "rules": {
   "locations": {
     "$uid": {
    ".read": "true",
       ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },  
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
     ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"      
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have structured my data with two directories

**locations**   READ - all users  WRITE - only the user that owns this data

**users**  READ /  WRITE - only the user that owns this data

When I set these rules my currently logged in user does not see their data anymore.

**DATABASE**
my format for saving `users/${this.uid}/stories`

I was using the UID as a way to make each user unique in the database.

**ERROR MESSAGE** from Firebase

> Error: permission_denied at /users/HBTaJt057Bf63oS771gah1allYe2/stories: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

I am not sure if I don't understand the concept or if I am missing some minor detail.  Any ideas would be truly appreciated.

Regards,
Jesse

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: If would also be useful to see the minimal **code** that is needed to reproduce the error.  The rules themselves seem fine, so likely the problem is in the way you read the data in the code.

Comment: Here is the repo for the code  https://github.com/JesseSoldat/Around-The-World-NG2-Firebase

Comment: I added the JSON DATA to the repo the file is called FIREBASE_DATA.json

Comment: Sorry Jesse, but that's not how Stack Overflow works. Please edit your question to include the [minimal code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it is quite useful).

Comment: Frank van Puffelent thanks for helping me understand the proper way to submit my questions. I will try to create another project only using Firebase and not AngularFire first and go on from there. Should I close this question and resubmit when I have the minimal code? Also what is the best format for the minimal code? GitHub repo? copies snippet?  Anyway once again thanks for your time.